# Shortening the length of a loop mid-run

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I have this code:

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4]

for i in range(0,len(numbers),1):
    print 'i = {} , len(numbers) = {}'.format(i,len(numbers))
    numbers.remove(i)
```

The output is :

```
i = 0 , len(numbers) = 5
i = 1 , len(numbers) = 4
i = 2 , len(numbers) = 3
i = 3 , len(numbers) = 2
i = 4 , len(numbers) = 1
```

My question is why didn't the loop stopped running once 'i' was bigger then 'len(numbers)'? (Line 4)

Thanks

Comment: `len(numbers)` has little to do with `remove` here. Add a `print numbers` to that loop and see how the list changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the list has no bearing here. To understand why, please keep reading.

Firstly, you're misunderstanding what the `range` function does. From the documentation:

> range(start, stop[, step]) This is a versatile function to create
>   lists containing arithmetic progressions. It is most often used in for
>   loops.

What `range` does is create a list (somewhat) of numbers (*python2*), and iterates across that.

```
>>> range(0, 5, 1)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This may look the same, but it is in fact, a completely different list. You can confirm this by assigning the return value to a variable and then printing out the `id()` of that, and then `numbers`.

What you want to do, is *iterate over the actual list*, rather than a list generated by the `range` function. You can do this by changing your loop definition slightly:

```
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

ctr = 0
for i in numbers:
    print('i = {} , len(numbers) = {}'.format(ctr, len(numbers)))
    numbers.remove(i)
    ctr += 1
```

Output:

```
i = 0 , len(numbers) = 5
i = 1 , len(numbers) = 4
i = 2 , len(numbers) = 3
```

Now, you see that, after each iteration, the list becomes shorter, until the list is exhausted before `i` hits 4.

To understand why, it happens like this:

```
Iteration 0
    0   1   2   3   4    (numbers)
   ctr

Iteration 1 (0 deleted)
    1   2   3   4        (numbers)
      ctr

Iteration 2 (1 deleted)
    2   3   4            (numbers)
           ctr

End (2 deleted)
```

Here, `ctr` is like a pointer, which points to the current element in the list. Each iteration of the loop, `ctr` is made to advance one step forward to the next element.

Now, each time you delete an element, not only does the list size shrink, but the iterator advances by *one* step, so you are virtually moving forward *twice*.

How do we prevent this? You've already happened upon the solution. Using `range`.

```
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

ctr = 0
for i in range(0, len(numbers), 1):
    print('i = {} , len(numbers) = {}'.format(ctr, len(numbers)))
    numbers.remove(i)
    ctr += 1
```

This is what happens:

```
Iteration 0 
    0   1   2   3   4   (numbers)
    0   1   2   3   4   (range)
    ctr


Iteration 1 (0 deleted)
    1   2   3   4       (numbers)
    0   1   2   3   4   (range)
        ctr

Iteration 2 (1 deleted)
    2   3   4           (numbers)
    0   1   2   3   4   (range)
           ctr

Iteration 3 (2 deleted)
    3   4               (numbers)
    0   1   2   3   4   (range)
               ctr

Iteration 4 (3 deleted)
    4                   (numbers)
    0   1   2   3   4   (range)
                   ctr

End (4 deleted)
```

And so, you get:

```
i = 0 , len(numbers) = 5
i = 1 , len(numbers) = 4
i = 2 , len(numbers) = 3
i = 3 , len(numbers) = 2
i = 4 , len(numbers) = 1
```

---

#### TL;DR

To summarise, when you iterate over a copy, the original list will shrink, meaning the length also decreases, but since you are iterating over a `range` object that returns a sequence of numbers from 0 to 4 (inclusive) and is not affected by the subsequent deletions, the loop will run for 5 iterations (equal to the number of elements returned by `range`).

Comment: Yes , looks like I misunderstood how the loop works. Thank you! :)